# Sacar data de una funcion

Tags: nodejs, promesas, function

Buenas, necesito sacar la variable "users" de esta funcion y del for loop, pense en usar promises pero soy nuevo con eso y no le encuentro la vuelta

```
  var ids = [
    "RtSG7NApoda9ycDRd7vm",
    "TnT9XOXnkD1Ra5ROJERR",
    "55fAOlOlejE3v0EUU4z9"
   ];

   var users = [];



 for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
  getData(ids[i]).then(function (data) {
   users.push(data);
  });
 }
```

Comment: puedes poner mas codigo, estan en una funcion?

Comment: No hay mas codigo, lo que necesito esta aqui. Es sacar users hacia fuera de ese for para usarla en el resto del codigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En este caso es necesario realizar una cola de promesas, usando el método `all` de la clase `Promise`.

[Documentación Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all)

Para realizar el procedimiento es necesario lo siguiente:

```
var ids = [1, 2, 3];

// Multiples datos
var data = function (ids) {
  var promises = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    promises.push(getData(ids[i]));
  }

  return Promise.all(promises);
}

// Ejecutar
data(ids).then(function (users) {
  console.log('Data:', users);
}, function (reason) {
  console.error('Exception', reason);
});
```

> En el caso que de que alguna promesa incluida retorne por el `reject()` el `Promise.all()` entrará por el en el segundo callback del `then()` y mostrará la razón por la que no se ha ejecutado correctamente.